# TCP retransmission different payload

Tags: tcp

I meet a strange problem. When tcp retransmission happen, it should be send same payload with missed packet. But i saw retransmission send different payload on windows system. Is it normal ? and any RFC explan this?

example 1:

1. tcp.seq:605921 tcp.len:546 ***this one missed***
2. tcp.seq:605921 tcp.len:1188 <- retransmission when timeout,but different length payload
3. **tcp.ack:607109** <-- Server acked #2

Example 2:

1. tcp.seq:4529820 tcp.len:419 ***this one missed***
2. tcp.seq:4530239 tcp.len:1460
3. **tcp.ack:4529820**
4. tcp.seq:4531699 tcp.len:92
5. tcp.seq:4529820 tcp.len:1460 <- retransmission #1 with different length payload
6. **tcp.ack:4531791** <- server acked #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP retransmission is not about sending missing **packets** again but about sending missing **data**. It might well happen that the retransmitted data get combined with following data in the same packet. Your question only shows a different **length** of the payload and not (as claimed in the title) a different payload. The resulting application data are likely the same, only they are packetized differently for transport.

Comment: @eeie9999: TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol. Packetizing is only done during the transport. If your application cannot deal with different kinds of packetizing (like expecting a single `recv` to exactly match a single `send`) then your application is broken. Unfortunately such misconceptions together with wrong expectations and resulting broken applications are not uncommon.

Comment: thanks, found same question and answer, https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/30019/tcp-retransmissions-with-additional-payload-data/