# Can there be several application layer (Modbus) PDUs in one TCP segment?

Tags: wireshark, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm analyzing some captured packets and see that for some of the packets, Wireshark displays the image below, which appears to contain several Modbus PDUs in the one TCP segment. I have searched online for answers but can't see this behavior anywhere I looked. From what I'm reading, Wireshark re-assembly gathers the different TCP segments, and so it appears this can't be reassembly.

My question is: is this behavior (i.e. having several Modbus PDUs in one TCP segment) normal and expected? If not, what is causing this problem? Is this an issue with Wireshark?

[image: Capture]
[link to fullsize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pRbQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Modbus TCP runs at the [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and supports multiple simultaneous transactions over a single connection (see page 10 of [the spec](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf)). So sending:

```
00 01 00 00 00 06 01 03 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 00 00 06 01 03 00 01 00 01
```

is fine (this is 2 x "Read Holding Register" commands - note the different transaction identifiers). If this is sent at the same time it's likely the two commands will be sent out in the same packet. While this is supported (by some devices!) its not something I see often (unless performance is key its easier to process the response before sending another request).

However I don't think this is what is happening in your case. The lines you are highlighting are flagged `TCP Retransmission` so I'm assuming there was a connectivity issue. You can also see this in the 1s gap between the retransmitted packed and the previous request (it looks like queries are being sent every 300ms).

862.493794
862.805685 - 0.3s gap
863.117588 - 0.3s gap
864.232576 1st retransmission - 1.1s gap

You will also note that after the retransmissions there are a couple of responses that come in very close together (less than 1ms apart).

When data is retransmitted I believe (not my area so relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397333/11810946) and assumptions!) that multiple packets may be combined. So I suspect you are seeing is:

- Network connectivity issue starts
- Client sends request
- No response received so Client tries again (may happen multiple times)
- Connectivity issue resolved
- The packets sent while there was an issue are combined and retransmitted (handled by the network stack).

Comment: This explanations is very helpful, thank you. I'm a bit unclear about supporting multiple transactions over a single connection. I thought a TCP connection is not same as a segment. Digging deeper (there are over 470,000 pkts!) I find the following: a) few times, that 'weird' segment appears without a re-transmission;  b) it appears to occur about every 30min with or without a retransmission;  c) the modbus transaction and unit identifiers is the same for all 11 transactions: 00 00 00 00 00 06 01 03 00 00 00 0b.  Shouldn't we have different IDs as you pointed out? What could be the problem?

Comment: You are correct TCP segments and packets (lower on the stack) are not the same thing. However the main answer stands (there can be more than one query in a TCP segment). I also believe the scenario shown above can still be the case (for example due to [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) delaying transmits - this could also explain what is happening every 30 mins if the ACK is delayed).

Comment: Ah I see. It's the first time I've heard of Nagle's algorithm. Thanks a ton for your response, it is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In no case does TCP ensure that if you send a packet of x bytes, the other end will receive the x bytes in a single packet.

It can happen that one side sends 1000 bytes and the other side receives first 800 and then 200, or two packets of 1000 and 2000 are sent and the other side receives only one of 3000.

From the received PDU, first you have to read the bytes necessary to obtain the length and then read the rest and so on to extract the PDUs